# Why I am getting this error when I try to open the Quantum Lab in the IBM Quantum experience?

Tags: programming, qiskit, ibm-q-experience

I am using quantum labs in IBM Quantum Experience to my circuits. But from yesterday onwards (May-03-2021) this error message is being shown on my screen. Does anyone have any idea about this issue?[image: Screenshot of error I am getting]

Comment: Hello @NavMohan ! The issue should be solved by now, do you still encounter this error?

Answer (score 1):

On the Qiskit slack there have been others who have the same issue connecting to Quantum Lab. A 503 Service Unavailable Error may be due to service maintenance or being overloaded. You may have to just wait for the server to return.